# Accessing Service Function from JavaScript Files

Tags: javascript, sails.js

quite new to Sails here (partially taking over another's project).
I've created a service and exported it:

```
module.exports = {
    schedule: schedule
};
```

So this can be accessed using Schedule.schedule.

I have a JavaScript file being loaded in my view, but when I try to call Schedule.schedule it says that "Schedule is not defined", and when I try to call:

```
sails.services.Schedule.schedule() or sails.controllers.Schedule.schedule()
```

It returns an error that "sails is not defined".

I've only used Angular in the past, but this is just sails, it looks like I can't access my controllers or services from the view though, is this correct?

Thanks =)

Comment: How do You load your script in the view? Are you putting the script inside <% %> tags (the default EJS tag for executing server side code)?

Comment: Hi, I'm just using standard HTML <script src="/js/cc-scheduler.js"></script>. This is loading up the files with no problems, but this file can't access the controllers or services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing to understand is that some of your code is run on the *Server* (which could be a node process that was `sails lift`ed on your local machine, or some remote linux box), and some of your code is run by the *browser* (chrome, firefox, etc).

Generally, these files won't be working together.

- Generally, scripts in `/assets` are run by the browser
- Generally, anything in `/api` is run by the server
- The whole `module.export` and `require` framework that sails provides is only available on the server, not in the browser.

Views are a somewhat confusing mixed case. Views are stored on the server, and when you use them, all code between the `<% %>` is run there on the server. But the rest of the file is treated as text, and not run or interpreted, including any included scripts.

Only in the browser is your script tag read and interpreted, and the script fetched and run. And there in the browser, there is no access to `module.exports`, the `sails` object, etc.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the information, I'll have to update my views to be able to run the server side code. I'll check some documentation to see how to include the `<% %>` part. Is it still possible to pass DOM elements to the server side? (this is essentially a form to schedule a task in the future)

Comment: No, you wouldn't usually pass a whole DOM element or DOM event or things like that to your server. It's annoying but necessary - in your script, you'll need to write an ajax call that sends a message to your server telling it to schedule the task. On the server you will have to write the controller method that receives that ajax call, and there you can use your modules to schedule the task. You really need to think of it as two isolated code environments that only communicate in short bursts, not pass code freely back and forth.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, appreciate the help, will start on that now =)